# insert text above title in report and graphics

Tags: positioning, titles, report

I want to insert text above the title name in report.

```
\title{This is the title}
\author{George\\
\\
\\
   \texttt{email}} 
\date{\today}
```

I want for example to print on the paper the institute."University of ..."
(Either above the title or below ,at the end of the page)
Also, if i want to include an image in this first page?

Comment: @HarishKumar Not a duplicate george ask how to place certain information on the title page, not to redefine the title page.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Not a duplicate george ask how to place certain information on the title page, not to redefine the title page.

Comment: @Sveinung To me it seems exactly the same as the question Harish refers to. I'll vote to close, but George can always ask for reopening if the answers there are not sufficient to solve his problem.

Comment: @egreg It is not the same question, but may be the answer can help, but also a lot of other suggestions. I would say that it would be a better policy to provide georg with an answer. For example, I see no reference to textpos in the referred answer. Actually, I start getting the feeling that I waste my time on this site.

Comment: @Sveinung Don't take it personally. As it stands, the question is not very clear and five people think that it's a duplicate. Nobody told you to remove your answer which I feel is valuable (out of votes for today, unfortunately), although probably not what the OP had in mind. But he can say more about this.

Comment: @egreg How many user are there on tex.stackexchange? The right policy is not to close the question within 10 minutes if it is unclear, but give the user the possibility, by friendly comments, to make it more precise. Then you may hint that another question is similar and may help. And then close the question.

Comment: @Sveinung: Please don't take it personally. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar I don't take anything personally, but suggest a more polite and friendly policy, and I refer, among others, to this question on Meta: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/do-we-like-non-tex-sx-moderator-activity-on-the-main-site (and the relevance is the text in the question and answer, not the question itself).

Comment: Sveinung's answer was more close to what i was looking for.As for the other post i didn't  find it when i was searching.Anyway

Comment: @HarishKumar Look at Georg’s comment. Maybe it had been better to hint him that his question could be misinterpreted. He was not looking for a redefinition of the title page.

Comment: @Sveinung: The linked answer was meant for adding additional information in the title page (not the re-definition of title page). Any how we are all here to help and learn. George can always ask for help through editing the question or through comments. Hence `closing` doesn't mean the end of road. Above all, I don't think anybody here (may be except you ;), no offense meant) has a crystal ball. Glad that your answer helped him. I already upvoted your answer.

Comment: I've reopened here, as there is an argument that the question is distinct from the suggested dupes. Perhaps the question could be edited to make it clearer how it differs from the linked ones?

Comment: @Sveinung I can see arguments both ways here: the 'LaTeX way' is I guess always to set up `\maketitle` to do the 'right thing', although in practice that's not what usually happens. On the basis that the OP seems to be after the approach taken in your answer, I've reopened.

Comment: @JosephWright My point is that the closing of questions has taken wrong direction. Look at the linked question and doncherry’s very friendly and politely comment and hint. And that question was not closed, instead Harish Kumar published an _excellent_ solution. In my opinion, that question can serve as a good example for how a closing procedure should work. And doncherry’s comments should be the standard text.

Comment: @Sveinung I have opened a meta question about the general issue: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set certain information at a given position on a page, I recommend the package [textpos](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/textpos). Ten you may set text at an absolute position on the page (typical for a logo or similar graphic), or relative to another text.

Below is an MWE placing a text on top right at the first page and a logo (the black box) at the bottom left. To change the positions, increase or decrease the first digit inside the parenthesis to move the text/graphics horizontal, increase or decrease the second digit for vertical movement.

```
\documentclass[demo,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

%\TPGrid[1mm,1mm]{10}{15} % Uncomment to have a grid on the page

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{5}(14,1)
\noindent\Large University of Nowhere
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{5}(1,27)
\includegraphics[height=1.cm,width=5cm]{Demo}
\end{textblock}


\title{MyThesis}
\author{M.\,Y.\,Alterego}

\maketitle
\section{Sirst section}
\Blindtext
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :Ok,thanks ,i was looking something like this.